# How can I translate the text in the invoice.pdf in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to translate the titles from the generated invoice.pdf in languages different than English. "Sold to", "Ship to", "Payment method" could not find where these strings are located in magento 2. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to introduce your own translation for a certain language via theme. Create a translation csv file under `<magento_install_dir>/app/design/frondend/<vendor>/<theme>/i18n/` and name it like your language code (eg. `en_US.csv` for english, `de_DE.csv` for german ...) For notation and other hints you can refer to the official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

That's really all you have to do. Magento 2 also has a neat trick to generate the translations file for you.

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="magento2/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/i18n/en_US.csv" magento2/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>
```

Just a hint: When you are translating strings that have variables passed into them, the output you see in english is sometimes put together by different strings. Easiest way to save some time here is to always look up the string you want to translate in the code not just the output. Also because you have to pass the variable in your translation.